# Prove that any element $g\in(\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$ of order $n$ can be written as $g = 1 + kn$ with $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

> Let $p$ and $q$ be two primes such that $p \nmid q-1 $ and $ q \nmid p-1$ (note that these two hypotheses could be superflous, but this is the context given by Paillier cryptosystem) and let $n = pq$. Prove that any element $g \in(\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$ of order $n$ is of the form $g = 1 + kn$ with $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

The reason behind this question is that I encountered this exercise while studying Paillier Cryptosystem. In the exercise was indeed asked firstly to prove that an element $g = 1 + kn$ with $\gcd(k,n) = 1$ has order exactly $n$, after that was asked to prove that every element of order $n$ can be written in that form. I was able to prove the first part considering binomial theorem and the fact that all terms vanish modulo $n^2$ except 1. But I did not figure out a way to prove the second part yet. I looked already for an answer but I could not find anything. Helpful hints or solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for the helpful clarification! I don't fully grasp why is necessary ( I suppose users that ask question in bad faith ), but I provided more details about the context and what I have done so far, hope it follows the guidelines now!

Comment: Your question is a reasonable one. But the reason it is necessary to provide context is  that students frequently ask assignment questions on this forum in the hope of getting easy answers that they don't need to think about. Also, there have been cases in the past couple of months of students posting exam questions while they were sitting online exams - there have been a couple of such cases at my institution (Warwick University).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will give you a hint. Given condition on $p,q$ implies that $\varphi(n) = (p-1)(q-1)$ and $n = pq$ are relatively prime. If $g\in(\mathbb{Z}/n^2\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is such that $g^n \equiv 1\bmod n^2$, then this necessarily means $g^n\equiv 1\bmod n$ obviously.

Now Euler's Theorem says $g^{\varphi(n)}\equiv 1\bmod n$ and you can now do a Euclidean Algorithm on the exponents to conclude that $g\equiv 1\bmod n.$